# How to disable enter button in a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML form:

```
<head>
<title>log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
user name : <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
user pass : <input type="password" name="pass"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
</body>
```

I want to make it so that the form can only be submitted by clicking the button - not by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. How can I do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Smarty...

Comment: @minitech is spot on; this is functionality that you need to use Javascript to accomplish, not a server-side templating system.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of solutions for that. Here is one of the simplest:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>log in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
        user name : <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
        user pass : <input type="password" name="pass"> <br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EFDZ2/

Comment: must i require jquery lab before??

Comment: @user1404047 No, there is no need in jQuery. It is plain JavaScript.

Comment: @user1404047 - Looks like it works to me: http://jsfiddle.net/N3vRg/ Note, this has *nothing* to do with Smarty.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - can i edit smarty class to make it work in templates ?

Comment: @user1404047 - [Smarty](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#basics-1) is a *templating engine* used to embed server-side/-parsed logic without requiring direct access to a PHP parser. When you say Smarty class, I don't know what you mean. Smarty "applications" are composed of files with a mix of information and template code, in which HTML, CSS and JS may be included (or something simple: a text file for sending a preformatted email message). The solution involves *HTML and Javascript*, no *Smarty*. *Maybe* `{literal}` is necessary to block parsing of CSS and JS.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - there is smarty folder with smarty.class.php and more files (it's inlude the functions like assign )

Comment: @user1404047 - Why are you so fixated on Smarty? Ignore it. **Do NOT touch the underlying Smarty PHP files.** The answer is no, you do not need to do anything with Smarty. Edit the *template file*.

Comment: @user1404047 - Look, this is HTML (which marks up content, mostly for display reasons in a browser context): `<input type="button" value="submit">` This is Javascript: `this.parentNode.submit();` This is an HTML attribute that sets an event handler: `onclick=""` Add the three together, and you get: `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();">` Markup only exists in transport to the browser, in which case the browsers turns it into DOM elements. `this.parentNode.submit()` tells the browser "get the parent element (`form` in this case) and call it's `submit()`".

Comment: @JaredFarrish - yes this code works in html form but not works in smarty .. In any case, thank you very much for your information

Comment: @user1404047 - By "doesn't work", what is a description of the behavior? Are you monitoring it with Firebug or Chrome Console to see if there are any Javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked best for me:

```
<input id="input_id" type="text">

<script>
    // prevent the enter key from submitting the form if input_id has focus to prevent accidental submission
    document.getElementById('input_id').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to VisioN's answer, there might be instances where the input is not a direct child of the form, so in these cases simply referring to the form as `this.form` will work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>log in</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
        user name : <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
        user pass : <input type="password" name="pass"> <br>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below script to the  section of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopRKey(evt) 
    {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement)?evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
   document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function checkKey(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if (!e) var e = window.event;

            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    $("input").keydown(checkKey);
})​
```

This should work in all browsers. It requires JQuery to make life simpler.
**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WDvvY/

Comment: Why do you check for `$.browser.mozilla`, only to do the same thing regardless of whether it's true?

Comment: Why do you check for `window.event`, even though jQuery already normalizes that?

Comment: You do not need jQuery to do this; plain Javascript would work just fine. And the other solution is more direct and simple to implement.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, I think the answer is simpler than that. If you don't want the Enter key to cause a submit, do not have a button or input of type "submit" in your form.
onsubmit="return false;" didn't do anything for me.
Firefox 27 and IE 11.