# How can i fire a function inside an input-field? or a default button with that function without actually submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

It works:
When the button is used

The problem is:
When pressing enter inside the text-field, the default action seems to be submit. I just want it to use the button available as default. Is this possible or will i have to highjack the enterpress with javascript?

Code:

```
<form>
<label>Password:<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"></label>
<input type="button" value="hämta data" onclick="getData('password.txt')"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774621/how-to-disable-enter-button-in-a-form

Answer (score 0):

By default, pressing Enter in the last field of a form submits the form. Try this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

so that submitting the form doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that this worked nice in combination of using a button-element instead. Then while pressing enter in the field that button is fired.